# Full width background slider

Tags: themes, slideshow

I want to create a webpage like [this](http://www.soneribank.com/). [This](http://www.inspuratesystems.com/learning/) is what I have created so far. I am looking to add a full width background slider to the website. Please guide me how can I do this in WordPress? Here is my frontpage code:

```
<?php
/**
 * The main template file
 *
 * This is the most generic template file in a WordPress theme and one
 * of the two required files for a theme (the other being style.css).
 * It is used to display a page when nothing more specific matches a query,
 * e.g., it puts together the home page when no home.php file exists.
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 */
get_header(); ?>

<div id="main-content" class="main-content">

<?php
    if ( is_front_page() && twentyfourteen_has_featured_posts() ) {
        // Include the featured content template.
        get_template_part( 'featured-content' );
    }
?>
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
        <?php
            if ( have_posts() ) :
                // Start the Loop.
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                    /*
                     * Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want to
                     * use this in a child theme, then include a file called called content-___.php
                     * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
                     */
                    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

                endwhile;
                // Previous/next post navigation.
                twentyfourteen_paging_nav();

            else :
                // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
                get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );

            endif;
        ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
    <?php get_sidebar( 'content' ); ?>
</div><!-- #main-content -->

<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

Comment: Do you have an idea how to create a slider in general for starters? You will have to figure that out _before_ WP bits are involved.

Comment: @Rarst: I have never created sliders but have used them for websites.

Comment: Rarst is absolutely correct.  You will need to spend some time learning the tricks of full-width images first.  Master the HTML and CSS and then you will know what you want from WordPress:  https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: @jdm2112: The biggest issue that I am facing is that when I place a slider behind the body of of the page, the content div  has a white background which makes the slider to not show at all. I want to hide the content div completely but keep the header, footer and sidebar on my front page.

Comment: So if `<div id="primary" class="content-area">` has the white background, why not simply update the CSS so it has your IMG as the background?

Comment: @jdm2112: Wouldn't that change the background of inner pages too? Thats something I don't want to do.